# VBA Macros behaves differently depending on selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight` subroutine that takes a merged cell as an argument and then fixes its height so that all the text will be visible. The `FixAll` sub is activated when a button is pressed.

The problem is it's behavior is unstable. When a cell is selected that is in the same column as the merged cell (column 4) the height is one size (smaller, but the text is 100% visible); when a cell is selected outside that column but inside a table nothing happens; when a cell is selected outside the table the height is fixed but get too big.

Why is this happening? I can't see anything related to a selected cell in the sub.

```
Sub FitAll()
   AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight (Cells(3, 4))
End Sub

Sub AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight(cell As Range)
    Dim CurrentRowHeight As Single, MergedCellRgWidth As Single
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single, PossNewRowHeight As Single
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        With cell.MergeArea
            .WrapText = True
            If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
                cell = cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)
                MsgBox (cell.Row & "and" & cell.Column)

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                CurrentRowHeight = .RowHeight
                ActiveCellWidth = cell.ColumnWidth
                For Each CurrCell In Selection
                    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + 
                        MergedCellRgWidth

                Next
                .MergeCells = False
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedCellRgWidth
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
                PossNewRowHeight = .RowHeight
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                .MergeCells = True
                .RowHeight = IIf(CurrentRowHeight > PossNewRowHeight, _
                CurrentRowHeight, PossNewRowHeight)

            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: I compare my results also to the same sub that doesn't use an argument but rather a selected cell. The results differ thought even after applying the changes [CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132462/8052882) suggested..

```
Sub AutoFitMergedActiveCellRowHeight()
    Dim CurrentRowHeight As Single, MergedCellRgWidth As Single
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single, PossNewRowHeight As Single
    If ActiveCell.MergeCells Then
        With ActiveCell.MergeArea
            .WrapText = True
            If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                CurrentRowHeight = .RowHeight
                ActiveCellWidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
                For Each CurrCell In Selection
                    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth

                Next
                .MergeCells = False
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedCellRgWidth
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
                PossNewRowHeight = .RowHeight
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                .MergeCells = True
                .RowHeight = IIf(CurrentRowHeight > PossNewRowHeight, _
                CurrentRowHeight, PossNewRowHeight)
            End If
        End With
    End If
    'MsgBox ("DONE")
    MsgBox (ActiveCell.Row & "and" & ActiveCell.Column)
End Sub
```

Comment: I take it that you are aware of this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381741/excel-adjust-height-of-merged-cells-automatically You might explore the differences in your own code.

Comment: @Variatus, Thank you, I'll check it out. Though I'd really liked to understand the problem with the code I have too..

Comment: The code can't work on selections comprising more than one row. We don't know your selection, Therefore it's hard to say what's wrong with the code. Anyway, the `FitAll` procedure specifies the range as D3. Therefore the subsequent reference to the Selection is bound to cause a problem as has been pointed out by @CLR in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each CurrCell In Selection` is looking at selected cell, not cell passed in parameter.

I think you want to replace:

```
For Each CurrCell In Selection
    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth
Next
```

with something like:

```
For Each CurrCell In cell.MergeArea
    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth
Next
```

Comment: Thank you!  But it's still a little different from using a macro based ob selection (added it to the question). The selection subroutine makes height smaller than this one. But why? If both essentially use the same Range - either selected or passed as an argument..

Comment: Figured it out.