# VBA How to set row height enter row cell inside maximum line number set in height

Tags: vba

Hi i am working in dynamic row height.  row 2 fill in VBA  dynamic .how to set in row height bellow 409 dynamic . Row 2 "A2 To AV2" Enter row set in which cell maximum number of line is available that line height set in Row 2. I have cell 2 data fix completed. Height how to fine biggest cell line number how to arrange in cell height.

```
Sub CallChildDate()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Dim s1,s2,s3,s11,s12,s13,s21,s22,s23,s32,s31,s33,s41,s42,s43,s51,s52,s53,s611,s621,s631,s61,s62,s63,s71,s72,s73,s81,s82,s83,s91,s92,s93,s101,s102,s103,s111,s112,s113,s121,s122,s123 As string

i = 2
s1 = "A" & i
s2 = "C" & i
S3 = "" & s1 & " : " & s2 & ""

s11 = "D" & i
S12 = "F" & i
S13 = "" & s11 & " : " & S12 & ""

s21 = "G" & i
s22 = "I" & i
S23 = "" & s21 & " : " & s22 & ""


s31 = "J" & i
s32 = "L" & i
S33 = "" & s31 & " : " & s32 & ""

s41 = "M" & i
s42 = "O" & i
S43 = "" & s41 & " : " & s42 & ""

s51 = "P" & i
s52 = "Z" & i
S53 = "" & s51 & " : " & s52 & ""

s611 = "AA" & i
s621 = "AB" & i
S631 = "" & s611 & " : " & s621 & ""

s61 = "AC" & i
s62 = "AD" & i
S63 = "" & s61 & " : " & s62 & ""

s71 = "AE" & i
s72 = "AG" & i
S73 = "" & s71 & " : " & s72 & ""

s81 = "AH" & i
s82 = "AJ" & i
S83 = "" & s81 & " : " & s82 & ""

s91 = "AK" & i
s92 = "AM" & i
S93 = "" & s91 & " : " & s92 & ""

s101 = "AN" & i
s102 = "AP" & i
S103 = "" & s101 & " : " & s102 & ""

s111 = "AQ" & i
s112 = "AS" & i
S113 = "" & s111 & " : " & s112 & ""


s121 = "AT" & i
s122 = "AV" & i
S123 = "" & s121 & " : " & s122 & ""



Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S3).Merge

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S3).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S13).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S13).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S13).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S23).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S23).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S23).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S33).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S33).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S33).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S43).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S43).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S43).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S53).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S53).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S53).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S631).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S631).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S631).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S63).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S63).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S63).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S73).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S73).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S73).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S83).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S83).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S83).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S93).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S93).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S93).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S103).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S103).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S103).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S113).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S113).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S113).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S123).Merge
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S123).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets("Spec Runner").Range(S123).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

'Worksheets("Spec Runner").Rows(i).RowHeight = 80.25

Dim a1 As String
Dim a2 As String
a1 = "A" & i
a2 = "AV" & i

Range(a1, a2).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
.LineStyle = xlSolid
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlSolid
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
.LineStyle = xlSolid
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
.LineStyle = xlSolid
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
End With

'END

'DATA ASSIGN IN CELL

Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = "2/10/2018"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value = "DAY"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 7).Value = "FL1"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 7).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 10).Value = "Oil pump motor"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 10).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 13).Value = "TESTING DATA"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 13).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 16).Value = "To disassemble cable power supply of Oil pump Draw stand 1, and Calender 2  for Maintenance interchange to use original motor pump complete set for same spec original design. Today we take out cable finish under maintenance follow up."
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 16).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 27).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 27).Value = "11:90"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 29).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 29).Value = "12:00"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 31).Value = "Test Description"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 31).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 34).Value = "Pradit K., Theerawan K., Boonriang P."
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 34).WrapText = True
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 37).Value = "Repair"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 40).Value = "Routine"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 43).Value = "Not yet"
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 46).Value = "Follow up"

End Sub
```

[image]

how to set in row height fixing.

Comment: Please use Option Explicit at the top of your code and declare all your variables.

Comment: ok Waite change now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381741/excel-adjust-height-of-merged-cells-automatically

Comment: I think your problem statement is how to show all the text in a merged cell. Setting the row height to the maximum required to display all text in the row including that of merged cells. In which case, you need to unmerge, autofit.... measure height, merge again and apply appropriate height.